# Not able to execute from PIL import Image in anaconda python 3.6

Tags: python, dll, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am unable to execute following

```
from PIL import Image
```

it returns me following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 56, in <
module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Currnetly using `PIL` version installed on anaconda `4.2.1`. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try:

```
conda update --all
```

If it doesn't help, this solution works for many people:

```
conda uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
```

Source: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945

Comment: After trying your solution. I found `ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-0f6709e38f49> in <module>()
----> 1 from PIL import Image

ImportError: cannot import name 'Image'`

Comment: @abhi1610, what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried `conda update --all; conda uninstall pillow; pip install pillow` . Last command gives me `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\abhi\anaconda3\lib\site-pack
ages (5.1.0)`. Now it shows me `ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 5.1.0
Pillow version: 4.2.1`

Comment: Try `pip install -U numpy` and `pip install -U pillow`.

Comment: If that doesn't help, try this: `pip uninstall pillow` and `pip install pillow==4.2.1`.